# Create file with specific formatting from directory contents

Tags: shell-script, files, text-processing, csh

I am using Solaris and csh.

In `$home/test` there are five files: `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt`, `d.txt` and `e.txt`.

If I run

```
% find $home/test/ -type f -print > ../filenames.txt
```

that file will look like:

```
/home/me/test/a.txt  
/home/me/test/b.txt  
…
/home/me/test/e.txt
```

I need to add `␣none` after each line, so that I can use the text file as the input to another script. i.e.:

```
/home/me/test/a.txt none  
…
/home/me/test/e.txt none
```

This simple problem is causing me issues.

Comment: Does the Solaris `find` implementation not support `printf` e.g. `find $home/test/ -type f -printf '%p none\n'` ?

Comment: @steeldriver No, `find -printf` is a GNU thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on bsd `find`

```
find $home/test/ -type f -print -exec echo '{} none' \; > ../filenames.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking in the `$home/test` directory only (not in the tree below it), this loop would also work:

```
for file in $home/test/*; do
    [ -f "$file" ] && echo "$file none"
done > ../filenames.txt
```